# Selenium - why the loaded cookies aren't fully working?

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, samesite

I've created a function(Selenium-Java) to login, save cookies and close current sesion. Then open the browser again and load those cookies(simulated).
The cookies were loaded and I'm loged in that page. But when I try to use one of the buttons from that page it doesn't work. Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong? Does it recognize that I'm using automation tools?
why the cookies don't have the param `SameSite`>

```
private void Play()throws InterruptedException{
driver.get("https://webpage.ro/");
LoadCookies();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'JOACĂ')]")).click();
sleep(5000);
SaveCookies();
```

}

```
private void LoadCookies() {
    try {
        File file = new File("src/test/java/Tests/cookies/" + contorStart + "_cookies.data");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String strline;
        while ((strline = Buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline, ";");
            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String name = token.nextToken();
                String value = token.nextToken();
                String domain = token.nextToken();
                String path = token.nextToken();
                String val = token.nextToken();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");  //Sun Feb 09 01:57:10 EET 2020
                Date expiry = df.parse(val);
                Boolean isSecure = Boolean.parseBoolean(token.nextToken());
                //Boolean isHtOnly = Boolean.parseBoolean(token.nextToken());
                Cookie ck = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure);
                driver.manage().addCookie(ck); // This will add the stored cookie to your current session
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Can't load cookies");
    }
}
private void SaveCookies() {
    File file = new File("src/test/java/Tests/cookies/" + contorStart + "_cookies.data");
    try {
        // Delete old file if exists
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
        // loop for getting the cookie information

        // loop for getting the cookie information
        int i = 0;
        for (Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
            i++;
            if (i != 4) {
                Bwrite.write((ck.getName() + ";" + ck.getValue() + ";" + ck.getDomain() + ";" + ck.getPath() + ";" + ck.getExpiry() + ";" + ck.isSecure()));//+";"+ck.isHttpOnly()));
                Bwrite.newLine();
            }
        }
        Bwrite.close();
        fileWrite.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Cookies not saved");
    }
}
```

[image: Console warnings/error]

Thank you!

Comment: Try to refresh the driver after loading the cookies

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not exactly an error but a fair warning by Chrome about future deprecation. The real problem is that error on the last line - 403. Which means the server is not authorizing you to call the particular API of that page. I think providing more information like what exactly you are doing, code, etc will be helpful.